# Is there any difference in meaning between "finish something in a week" and "finish something after a week"?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference in meaning between *finish something in a week* and *finish something after a week*? For example:

> I'll finish the job **in** a week.
>
> I'll finish the jon **after** a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"in a week" can either mean one week from right now, or a week after starting the job. So, for example, someone might say:

"I'll finish the job in a week." If they just accepted the job and are telling the client when they'll have it done. They'll have it done 1 week from today.

You could also say "I'll finish the job in a week" if you are trying to convince someone to hire you and are telling them that hypothetically, if they were to hire you, you would have the job done a week after starting.

"I'll finish the job after a week" only means the second version of the first statement. It means that one week after you start working, the job will be done. But this sounds awkward. Nobody would say this in everyday speech. "in a week" is better.